# Kendo UI grid filtering called twice

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a kendo grid with filtering enabled. When trying to enhance performance I found out, that filtering triggers backend 2 times. Found out that it triggers when I `press key` in column search field and also when I press `Enter`.

Is there a way to turn off automatic filtering, so that user could enter filter data and perform filtering only when user approves it with `Enter`?

Is there some setting to control filter *automatic/on-submit* behavior? I guess it might be done implementing custom filters or something like that, but that sounds like an overkill for a simple behavior..

This is how filter options are set for the grid.

```
filterable: {
    mode: "row",
    operators: {
        string: {
            contains: "Contains"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yea, that's the autocomplete feature, sending a request for every keypress.
Every keypress is fetching data from the server for populating dropdown selection.

You can avoid ti by adding class in your filter template:

```
filterable: {
    cell: {
       template: function(e){
           e.element.addClass("k-textbox");
       }
    }
}
```

**NOTE:** filter will be triggered on `Enter` and on `focus-out` event.

You can start from this example: [No autocomplete](https://dojo.telerik.com/EbOYobaD)

Or you can use `minWidth` before sending search request for populating dropdown selection:

```
 filterable: {
     cell: {
         minLength: 10
     }
 }
```

[Min length](https://dojo.telerik.com/EhOXADiM)

Comment: Thanks! One thing - it seems that it must be added to each column separately

Comment: yep, for every string column